# How to find the DKIM selector without being the owner of the domain?

Tags: dns, email, dkim

it seems the emails of my client are always landing in my Spam folder. I suspect his DKIM TXT record is missing (or even the subdomain at all). I would like to validate this before suggesting help on that matter. He is not very tech-savvy, so he won't know it (anymore), probably.

My question is: Can I find the DKIM selector from his domain by my own? If so, how?

Comment: Don't you have access to your clients zonefile or some UI or API access to be able to see all their records? Because otherwise you can not find the specific `TXT` record, besides testing some heuristics or having access to some email that ought to have used it.

Comment: I closed this because it appears to be about debugging email sent by somebody else and not about running your own website.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller Ok, out of curiosity, what StackExchange site would've been the right to ask this?

Comment: @PatrickMevzek I have not, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I don't know of a Stack Exchange site that would be appropriate for this question.

Comment: In case people are still curious about this, https://registry.prove.email can let you get DKIM selectors for domains that you haven't received an email from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume your client has sent an email to you at some stage, in the headers search for ‘DKIM-Signature’ to find the DKIM signature applied to the message.

This DKIM-Signature contains an attribute ‘s=’ which is the selector used.

You could always try `default` as the selector and test it here: https://easydmarc.com/tools/dkim-lookup

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful and I decided to mark your answer as accepted. It appears there is no DKIM signature and I could pin point that even an SPF entry is missing, so no wonder all his emails are treated as spam. I could convince him to help him out on that matter. Anyways, have a nice day, Steve.